# Do ruby on rails programmers refactor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I'm a Java programmer who started programming Ruby on Rails one year ago. I like the language, rails itself and the principles behind them. But something that bothers me is that Ruby programmers don't seem to refactor.

I noticed that there is a big lack of tools for refactoring in Ruby / Rails. Some IDE's, like Aptana and RubyMine seem to offer some very basic refactoring, but nothing really big compared to Eclipse's Java refactorings.

Then there is another fact: most railers (even the pros) prefer some lightweight editors, like VIM or TextMate, instead of IDEs. Well, with these tools you just get zero refactoring (only regex with find/replace).

This leaves me this impression that rails programmers don't refactor. It might be just a false impression, of course, but I would like to hear the opinion of people who work professionally with ruby on rails.

Do you refactor? If you do, how do you do it,with which tools? If not, why not?

Comment: All programmers refactor.  That's the difference between a programmer and a code monkey.  Except of course Jon Skeet, whose code refactors itself as he writes it and is optimal and error free for the first compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Most Rails programmers try and follow a Test first, write code to pass the test, then refactor the code BEFORE they go onto the next test.

Do ALL rails/ruby programmers... probably not, but as far as a 'vibe' or 'feel' in this community, I'd say it's something that is preached and practiced enough that it happens more times than not.

There is no need for IDEs imo.  VIM, emacs and/or textmate is enough for Ruby and most rails programmers.  I guess Java needed more compiling or something, what do I know about that though, as I've only programmed in Ruby.  Why do all Java programmers use IDEs (since I'm generalizing).

Comment: pjammer has a good point: the testing that is part of the Ruby culture encourages testing, which leads to refactoring early and often.  Therefore, we usually don't let our code get bloated enough to need the power of an IDE.

Comment: So, you refactor manually, i.e., moving code with a editor? I agree this might be enough for smaller refactorings (in a red-gree-refactor cycle), but doesn't it gets to slow for bigger design changes?

Comment: personally, as an app grows, i build to the features I have a need for.  As i add a second feature, let's say, that could use some of the first feature's methods (one  or two usually) I'll pull them into their own module or class in the lib library. As they get more involved, that's when you use a gem... But as you build, you see how to use things. so yes, as I create a new module, i often just cut and paste to be honest. As for the text editors, most of us know the keyboard shortcuts and well, that is all we need to move them (especially vim).

Answer (score 19):

#### Definitely yes, there is a different reason for the tool disparity

---

***An IDE is more practical to construct for Java***

Java's strict typing and documented grammar make it possible to write language-parsing IDE tools

Ruby's duck typing and documented-by-the-Yacc-source grammar make it quite difficult to do so.

***An IDE is more needed for Java***

Java's verbosity makes code-writing and code-rewriting tools desireable.

Ruby's extremely terse nature combined with the typically-no-type-declarations (of course they do appear inline with `Type.new`) make such things optional.

***Combining the two...***

So the combination of *really hard to write* coupled with *not actually needed* results in the balance tipping in favor of people's favorite editors.

Giving up vi(1) for an IDE is something I would rather not do, but I do with Java because I need the IDE to write my interface implementations and such, and the fact that it parses Java makes it useful in code completion.  Since with Ruby it can't and I don't need it anyway, I stick with vi(1) and TextMate.

***Summary***

Since you aren't buried in code, it's possible to refactor with a few reasonable edits. But while on the subject of "other Ruby developers", my Ruby question is: why does everyone (except me it seems) use function parens?  Because in a few % of situations they are needed, and so the "inconsistency" is disturbing?

Comment: Great answer. Regarding the use of function parens, I almost always use them except when working with a DSL such as Rails validations. Without parens, they look like an instruction rather than a method call. Maybe it's just how I've been taught, but `validates_presence_of :name` seems cleaner than `validates_presence_of(:name)` when written on a single line. Most Rails code that I've seen has been pretty consistent with this, but it's hard to say what everyone is doing.

Comment: Parens are always unambiguous, while simply lines without parens are always English. People have general preferences, and the context always comes into play. In a DSL, in particular, we tend not to use parentheses: Rails Routes, RSpec, Rakefile, Gemfile, ActiveRecord Relations/Scopes, ActionController Filters, Sinatra.

Comment: @DigitalRoss Good answer. There is one thing I am a bit confused about ...  I was wondering, why do rails developers refactor less? Say I decide to slightly change an object due to changes in my domain language - I would have to manually change the name of the file, and change all appearance of that object in tests, etc. In Java with an IDE such as eclipse, I could simply change the name of the file, and everything else is done automatically.

Answer (score 6):

RoR developers **do** refactor a lot. But most importantly they do it because they can do it easily.

If you keep to the main principle of RoR - Do not Repeat Yourself - and spent some time on code design (which means you didn't happen to create a huge chunk of monolithic code), nothing can stop you to rewrite a piece of code, whatever is in your mind (generalization, speedup, improving readability, etc.). The built-in testing/benchmarking/profiling functionality of Rails is at your service to check if you achieved your goal without sacrificing already existing and working functionality.

The editor is totally independent of the code, therefore you could even use Notepad for coding (I'm not a command-line fanatic, I prefer a bit more 'graphical' editors like Gedit).

Answer (score 2):

Having spent a lot of time in both Java and Ruby (with a good bit of back-and-forth of late, from Eclipse to/from Textmate) I agree that certain kinds of refactorings are harder in Ruby. This is less a consequence of poorer IDEs for Ruby than it is the fact of static typing vs. dynamic typing and the difficulty of writing refactoring tools for a dynamic language. To a large degree manual/regex driven refactoring is easier in Ruby than it would be in Java because of the terseness of Ruby code -- there's just less of it --, but nevertheless something as simple as renaming a method is not as straightforward in Ruby as it is in Java. The benefits of Ruby vs. Java are (imo) greater by far (and you'll just have to use Ruby in production for a few months to get a real feel for just how much you'll love it), but one drawback is the lack of the same robust refactoring that you're used to in tools like IDEA and Eclipse.

EDIT: And just to be clear -- I don't do any less refactoring in Ruby per se than Java, but it seems I need it less for Ruby. But when I do I rely on unit tests rather than the compiler as I would in Java.